# Multi-Class Classification in Caffe of HDF5 data

Tags: classification, deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I have 900 one-dimensional data as training data and 100 one-dimensional data as test data. I stored my data as .hdf5 files.
For binary classification (e.g. 0 and 1) I used Caffe and I am quite satisfied with the result.

But now I need to build a deep learning model in Caffe for multi-class classification (e.g. 1,2,3,4 classes). Can anyone please help me out about how can I train the Caffe network for multi-class classification?

Comment: what loss layer were you using for the binary classification?

Comment: SoftmaxWithLoss layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same SoftmaxWithLoss for multiclass problems. The only difference is that in the last layer you should have one channel for every class, and the label data should be numbered 0,1,...C-1, where C is your number of classes. You can check an example in [alexnet](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt) where they train a model for 1000 classes (ImageNet). You can see that in the last layer (before the loss) they have 1000 outputs.